# Error :Cannot instantiate the type Select in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, class, selenium, select

I am testing a website with selenium webdriver.
I have imported all the jar files also, but still could not use Select Class in eclipse. It gives me an error: `Select class cannot be instantiated.`
I have also imported `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select`

Following is my source code

```
import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Dropdown {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.makemytrip.com");
          WebElementaddress=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='to_typeahead1']"));
        Select sc = new Select (address);  // ERROR LINE
        sc.selectByIndex(5);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not use phrases like "Help me ASAP" since they are counted as pretty impolite. Noone will help you if you are impolite.

Comment: You could provide us some HTML code of the select element you are trying to find with `@id='to_typeahead1'`

Comment: @Dakkaron , ok i will take care of this  in future.

Comment: @spcial, actually the issue i am getting is , i cannot use Select class in my Program. even after importing  the needed Packages.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the below. Lets break it down into parts.

```
Select sc = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("your Xpath match case"))); 
                                 **//this will get the dropdown into sc object**
List<WebElement> we = sc.getOptions();  **//to get the options values into list**
System.out.println(we.size());  **//to print the size in console, this and
                                  previous lines for debug/cross checking**
sc.selectByIndex(5);  **//this will select the 5th index and 6th value(indexing starts from 0)**
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for reply , but with this also i will get error , as i am getting error while using **Select class**.

Comment: Hi @dikshit, please remove `import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;
` and retry, that should work

Answer (score 0):

`Import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select; package in your project, instead of org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;`

Error will go off.

Answer (score -1):

I see that the Xpath you have provided is not correct.
It should be  `.//*[@id='to_typeahead1']`

Moreover, this element is not a select box. Its an input box.
What you can probably try is to click on the element and then try to click on the option you want to select.

Comment: This is a valid xpath grammer

Comment: Actually that occurs while pasting here, in my code its with *
And I was trying to click and dropdown will open and then i will select the item on index 5.
By the way thanks for replying.

Answer (score -2):

I have used the `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select` package and it worked fine.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NewClassTest {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    @Test
    public void selectOption() {
        driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select");

        WebElement address = driver.findElement(By.tagName("select"));
        Select ab = new Select(address);
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Good answers address the specific problem.